# How to limit access to an html file

Tags: php, html

I'm new to PHP, I'm interested in PHP... I tried making a login form in HTML (form.html). And wrote a piece of PHP code to check the username and password and link to another HTML (test.html) file... But if I tried opening "/test.html" It opened... I need to limit access to test.html to users that have logged in... I've attached the code below... Thanks!

```
<?php
    $userName = $_POST['username'];
    $passWord = $_POST['password'];

    if($userName == 'username' and $passWord == 'password'){
        header("location:test.html");
    }
    else{
        echo 'Login Failed, Username or Password maybe incorrect. Try again by refreshing the page.';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't (usually) execute at all on a .html file.  If you want it to be authenticated by PHP, it should be a PHP file. As you have it set up, anyone can access test.html.  So:

1. Make it a PHP file, and then at the top of your PHP pages, check if the user is logged in.
2. Set a Session variable on login so other pages can check if the user is logged in.

login.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // If we're already logged in, skip the login form
    if ( isset( $_SESSION['username'] ) ){
        header("location:test.php");
        exit;
    }

    $userName = $_POST['username'];
    $passWord = $_POST['password'];

    if($userName == 'username' and $passWord == 'password'){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $userName
        header("location:test.php");
    }
    else{
        echo 'Login Failed, Username or Password maybe incorrect. Try again by refreshing the page.';
    }
?>
```

test.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( ! isset( $_SESSION['username'] ) ){
    http_response_code( 403 );
}

...
?>
```

Comment: What about `session_start()`?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Oops! I put that in my include that connects to the DB, so I end up forgetting it in examples

Answer (score 0):

Files are restricted by adding user sessions. You can start a user session on user login and check the session to on every file request to make sure which user it is (to serve the right data) and also to if she has the authority to access it.

```
<?php
// Set session variables
$_SESSION["username"] = "name";
$_SESSION["user_id"] = "id";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Then in your PHP files check the session

```
<?php
 if ( ! isset( $_SESSION["user_id"] ) ){
 die();
}
?>
```

Comment: Probably a bit safer to check a specific Session var than Session itself. `if ( ! isset( $_SESSION["user_id"] ) ){...`